# emulator shutting down when I click on the text box created by React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Hey i am fairly new to react native and the android emulator keeps crashing when i click on the text box which i created using TextInput tag.
Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) 
 This error appears in the android studio

[Input.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i18jQ.png)

[LoginForm.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQTkH.png)

[Android Emulator screen with the text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yll3.png)

[Error in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCTru.png)

Comment: Do you try to run your app from android studio or you use 'react-native run-android' on terminal?

Comment: You can use remote debugging to detect what cause the crashing error..

Comment: @Reza I run the app using my terminal with that command.

Comment: @digit Can you please guide me as to how i can go about debugging the app for windows?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to enable the debugging on the console. Use the following link:

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging

Then you should always check your terminal that yarn has been started there, because some errors can be visible there. Currently I think, this error that you see inside android studio is not a real error. So the first step is to find the real error from a right place. Update me when you see the real error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried debugging the app by using the "Debug JS remotely" option in the developer menu but that again causes the emulator to crash with the same error in the studio. In fact using any option in the developer menu makes the emulator crash.